# why can i not use break on this code and what can i use instead? python

Tags: python

The task that I am doing is to develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.

```
sentencelist=[] #variable list for the sentences
word=[] #variable list for the words
positions=[]
words= open("words.txt","w")
position= open("position.txt","w")

question=input("Do you want to enter a sentence? Answers are Y or N.").upper()
if question=="Y":
    sentence=input("Please enter a sentance").upper() #sets to uppercase so it's easier to read
    sentencetext=sentence.isalpha or sentence.isspace()
    while sentencetext==False: #if letters have not been entered
        print("Only letters are allowed") #error message
        sentence=input("Please enter a sentence").upper() #asks the question again
        sentencetext=sentence.isalpha #checks if letters have been entered this time

    word = sentence.split(' ')
    for (i, check) in enumerate(word): #orders the words
        print(sentence)

        word = input("What word are you looking for?").upper() #asks what word they want
        if (check == word):
            positionofword=print("your word is in this position:", i+1)
            positionofword=str(positionofword)
        else:
            print("this didn't work") #print error message

elif question=="N":
    print("The program will now close")
else:
print("you did not enter one of the prescribed letters")

words.write(word + " ")
position.write(positionofword + " ")
```

The problem for me is that I am stuck in the loop of:

```
   word = input("What word are you looking for?").upper() #asks what word they want
    if (check == word):
        positionofword=print("your word is in this position:", i+1)
        positionofword=str(positionofword)
    else:
        print("this didn't work") #print error message
```

Which therefore means that I cannot get the words into the file. I have tried to use break, but that did not work out for me because I could not get the words into the file.

I'm new to this site, but I've been stalking for quite a while. Hopefully this is right, I'm open to hearing criticism if I've worded this wrong.

Comment: Move `print(sentence)` and `word = input("What word are you loo...` outside of the loop.

Comment: Stephen Rauch if I do that, then I get the sentence printed 6 times, but it does work with what i need it to do. how do i avoid the sentence being printed 6 times?

Comment: Did you move the `print(sentence)` outside of the loop?

Comment: You might also want to consider using a variable name other than `word` in `word = sentence.split(' ')` since it doesn't describe what it is, and later on you use that variable to accept input. Try `sentence_words`!

Comment: Jammeth_Q thank you.

Comment: Stephen Rauch I did yes, but now it has a problem with my elif? I added an else to balance it but it still has a problem with the elif.

Comment: The answer to that depends on how you want your program to work. If they don't type "Y" should it automatically assume they don't want to enter a sentence? If so, just use `else` with no condition (no `question=="N"`). If you'd like to have something to catch if they entered something that wasn't "Y" or "N", just make sure your `else` is after your `elif`.

Comment: Jammeth_Q I'd like to have something to catch if the don't enter N, purely for the program breaking sake. My else is straight after my elif, but before the file writing. Which also doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: and now the problem is it's not going into the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in the for loop is incorrect - rather than asking once what the word the user wants to find, you ask that for each word in the sentence, and only match if they enter the word they want when that is the current word being checked. You are also printing the sentence once for each word in the sentence. Restructure it like so:

```
print(sentence)
sentence_words = sentence.split(' ')
word = input("What word are you looking for?").upper() #asks what word they want
for (i, check) in enumerate(sentence_words): #orders the words
    if (check == word):
        print("your word is in this position:", i+1)
        positionofword=i+1
        break
else:
    print("This didn't work")
```